# List taxonomy terms as links

Tags: taxonomy

How can I make a list of links of all the taxonomy terms I'm using? For example, I have a taxonomy of Manufacturers with terms of Honda, Ford, etc. I want to list out those terms as links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My apologies. After some more searching, I found that I could pass the taxonomy as an argument in wp_list_categories. [Here is the info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_Terms_in_a_custom_taxonomy) via Wordpress Codex.